# ERROR TypeError: commands.find is not a function

Tags: angular-routing, angular6

I want to navigate user from one route to next route. But this error is coming when i call the navigate function of Router class.

```
this.router.navigate('/');
```

I have imported the class on Top `import {Router} from '@angular/router';` and initialized an object like `private router: Router` on Component's constructor.

The function is working proper in other components.

Is this because of i am already in path / and navigate to the same ?

Please help to make me understand.

Console Log Error : [Image File](http://prntscr.com/k6xdrm)

Component Code :

```
import {Component, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {NgxDrpOptions, PresetItem, Range} from 'ngx-mat-daterange-picker';
import {APP_CONFIG, AppConfig} from '../../config/app.config';
import {IAppConfig} from '../../config/iapp.config';
import {ProgressBarService} from '../shared/progress-bar.service';
import {HeroService} from '../../dashboard/shared/hero.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-exp',
  templateUrl: './exp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./exp.component.scss']
})

export class ExpComponent implements OnInit {

  appConfig: any;
  menuItems: any[];
  progressBarMode: string;
  currentLang: string;
  range:Range = {fromDate:new Date(), toDate: new Date()};
  options:NgxDrpOptions;
  presets:Array<PresetItem> = [];

  constructor(@Inject(APP_CONFIG) appConfig: IAppConfig,
              private progressBarService: ProgressBarService,
              private translateService: TranslateService,
              private heroService: HeroService,
              private router: Router) {
    this.appConfig = appConfig;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setDefaultValues();
  }

  setDefaultValues() {
    this.setCalender();
    if (!this.heroService.getCompanyId()) {
      this.heroService.setCompanyId(11);
    }
    if (!this.heroService.getLocationId()) {
      this.heroService.setLocationId(null);
    }
    if (!this.heroService.getStartDate() || !this.heroService.getEndDate()) {
      this.heroService.setDates(Date.now()-86400, Date.now());
    }
  }

  setCalender() {
    const today = new Date();
    const fromMin = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth()-11, 1);
    const fromMax = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate()-1);
    const toMin = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth()-11, 2);
    const toMax = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate());

    this.setupPresets();
    this.options = {
                presets:this.presets,
                format: 'Date',
                range: {fromDate:fromMax, toDate:toMax},
                applyLabel: "Submit",
                calendarOverlayConfig: {
                  shouldCloseOnBackdropClick: false
                },
                cancelLabel: "Cancel",
                excludeWeekends:true,
                fromMinMax: {fromDate:fromMin, toDate:fromMax},
                toMinMax: {fromDate:toMin, toDate:toMax}
              };
  }

  //handler function that receives the updated date range object
  updateRange(range:Range) {
    this.range = range;
    this.heroService.setDates(this.range.fromDate, this.range.toDate);
    this.router.navigate('/');
  }

  updateLocation(location_id) {
    this.heroService.setLocationId(location_id);
  }  

  //helper function to create initial presets
  setupPresets() {

    const backDate = (numOfDays) => {
      const today = new Date();
      return new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() - numOfDays));
    }

    const today = new Date();
    const yesterday = backDate(1);
    const minus7 = backDate(7)
    const minus30 = backDate(30);
    const currMonthStart = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 1);
    const currMonthEnd = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth()+1, 0);
    const lastMonthStart = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth()-1, 1);
    const lastMonthEnd = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 0);

    this.presets =  [
      {presetLabel: "Yesterday", range:{fromDate:yesterday, toDate:today}},
      {presetLabel: "Last 7 Days", range:{fromDate: minus7, toDate:today}},
      {presetLabel: "Last 30 Days", range:{fromDate: minus30, toDate:today}},
      {presetLabel: "This Month", range:{fromDate: currMonthStart, toDate:currMonthEnd}},
      {presetLabel: "Last Month", range:{fromDate: lastMonthStart, toDate:lastMonthEnd}}
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post your error log and component code.

Comment: Done @hrdkisback. I have added log and the component file code. Please check.

Comment: I think issue is in `this.router.navigate('/');`, Try `navigateByUrl` method. `navigate` method expects a array and you are passing a string.

Comment: Thanks for the Guidance @hrdkisback .

Answer (score -1):

1. Navigate requires an array of strings like this

   this.routes.navigate(["/home"]);
2. The second solution might be

   this.router.navigateByUrl("/");

Comment: The 2. solution `this.router.navigateByUrl(["/"]);` is not valid, NavigateByUrl expects a string not an array of strings.